# Getting started with this ARM7 board

Tags: linux, embedded, jtag, arm7

This bad boy arrived in the post recently. But, didn't have any instructions, CD-ROM or Dev Kit stuff.

Despite lack of instructions, I'm pretty sure we should be able to get it going with DS-5, a JTAG cable and embedded linux. The goal is to get a small web server/site running on it.

It's an UB4020EVB board with SEP 4020 ARM7 chip. Has JTAG, USB and ethernet connections.

Does anyone know a) What hardware kit I need to get it up and running with an OS, and b) if there's any particular JTAG cable we need.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

T

[image]

Comment: Looks like an interest board/problem, but not a programming one.

Comment: This happens when you try to safe few bucks on a dev board, instead of buying something well known, like [Embedded Artists LPC boards](http://www.embeddedartists.com/products/kits). Wish you good luck in searching the u-boot and kernel patches among with other relevant info in [chinese](https://www.google.com/search?q=UB4020EVB)!

Comment: The 20-pin connector named 'ARM JTAG' looks standard. Any ARM JTAG cable should fit.

Answer (score 1):

Good luck; all the data I can find on this is in Chinese.  Apart from that ARM7 is not a good platform for Linux since it lacks an MMU.  uCLinux will run without an MMU, but rather misses much of the benefit of using Linux in the first instance.